# CreateProcess error=2 The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have recently started using Android Studios and have already come up to a pretty irritating problem, help please.

Error:org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Its your file does not exists `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat`.

Comment: It does, I have entered the path in my documents search and has been found.

Comment: Did you escape the "\" (back slash)

Comment: As long as you're removing the 'dx.bat' from the end it searches correctly

Comment: But the dx does exist within the folder

Comment: And when I double click on it, it comes up with an error saying that the file can't be found

Comment: This is all information that should be in the question. If your o/s can't find a file you just clicked on, the problem doesn't seem to be related to Java... try reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with IntelliJ.  It happened after the new M release for Android. When I would try to build an APK or Make the project it would show ...CreateProcess error = 2. Even though the file was actually there.

It turned out that I could not run the SDK manager either.  That may be because I'm running Android Studio on the same computer.  So I switched to Android Studio and opened the SDK manager there.  It showed that I needed to update or load about 19 files.  After installing the updates, I went back to IntelliJ, ran my project and the error was gone.

So try opening the SDK manager and running the updates, and installing any missing files.